# PHP: what is actually "parameter 1" in warnings?

Tags: php, syntax

This may be a basic PHP syntax question, but I could not get any results from search. So, in warning or error messages, what does actually "parameter 1" mean? Like in this example:

```
Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in ...
```

It is not to solve this special warning, but my question is, to what parameter 1 refers to. Is it imagecopyresized(parameter1,parameter2,...)? Or are these called arguments? I could not really understand the wikipedia article about parameters ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29))

Comment: you are in the right path.. its the first argument passed to the imagecopyresized() function

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms *arguments* and *parameters* are used interchangeably. Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) php page which talks about them and you will notice they use both terms.

Answer (score 4):

```
imagecopyresized($a, $b, $c);
```

`$a` is `parameter 1`. `$b` is `parameter 2`, `$c` is ... well I think you got it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "parameter 1" refers to the first argument (aka parameter) that was passed to the function.